# Prove that $|f'(z)|>0$ for a power series expansion $f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ satisfying $\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|$,

Tags: complex-analysis

Q. Let $f(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0} a_n z^n$ be an analytic function on the open unit disc $D$ around $0$ with $a_1 \neq 0$. Suppose that $\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|$. Then which of the following are true?

(A) There are only finitely many such $f$.

(B) $\left|f^{\prime}(z)\right|>0$ for all $z \in D$.

(C) If $z, w \in D$ are such that $z \neq w$ and $f(z)=f(w)$, then $a_1=-\sum_{n \geq 2} a_n\left(z^{n-1}+z^{n-2} w+\cdots+\right.$ $\left.w^{n-1}\right)$

(D) $f$ is one-one on $D$.

I think that there are infinitely many such functions as we have $f_k(z)=\sum_{n \geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}z^n$ satisfies the premise for $k>1$ (I would greatly appreciate the objections on my argument). How can I connect the condition $\sum_{n \geq 2}\left|n a_n\right|<\left|a_1\right|$ to the derivative to deal with option (B)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, then $f'(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} na_n z^{n-1} = \sum_{n \ge 1} na_n z^{n-1}$. Thus,
$$
|f'(z)|=\left|\sum_{n \ge 1} na_n z^{n-1}\right|\ge \left|a_1\right|-\left|\sum_{n \ge 2} na_n z^{n-1}\right|\ge |a_1|-\sum_{n \ge 2} n|a_n||z|^{n-1}.
$$
Thus, inside the disk $|z|< 1$, we have
$$
|f'(z)|\ge |a_1|-\sum_{n \ge 2} n|a_n|>0.
$$

Comment: I hope you have taken the last step "Thus, inside the disk...." with the help of minimum modulus principle, but it needs derivative $f'(z)$ to be non vanishing, right?

Comment: No, it's just that when $|z|<1$, we have $|z|^k<1$ for any positive $k$ as well. So it's just a simple lower bound estimate.

Comment: Ya...I got it...